# How to upload multi images in one post and how to show them according to their orders in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I want my post to have many images in its content so I decided to make post table and one to many relationship with images so one post can have many images.. question is when i build a new post how can I upload these multiple images and how to save them in orders in database so i can get them back according to this order.

I just wanna know the best and simplest way to make this post has many images in laravel.

Thanks you.

Comment: Can you please share what you have tried already. How the images are being stored now (controller, view etc)  so we can advise on the issue of ordering

Comment: I did not create any because i do not have the full idea in my head all I need way to make my post can has multi images in its content. by how can i do that while creating the post how to upload how to assign the place or the order of this image in the content.